# How can I model my meteor collection to feed three different reactive views

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-modeling

I am having some difficulty structuring my data so that I can benefit from reactivity in Meteor. Mainly nesting arrays of objects makes queries tricky.

The three main views I am trying to project this data onto are

1. waiter: shows order for one table, each persons meal (items nested, essentially what I have below)
2. kitchen manager: columns of orders by table (only needs table, note, and the items)
3. cook: columns of items, by category where started=true (only need item info)

Currently I have a meteor collection of order objects like this:

```
   Order {
      table: "1",
      waiter: "neil",
      note: "note from kitchen",
      meals: [
         { 
           seat: "1",
           items: [ {n: "potato", category: "fryer", started: false }, 
                    {n: "water", category: "drink" } 
           ]
          },
          { 
           seat: "2",
           items: [ {n: "water", category: "drink" } ]
          },
      ]
   }
```

Is there any way to query inside the nested array and apply some projection, or do I need to look at an entirely different data model?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're building this app for one restaurant, there shouldn't be many active orders at any given time—presumably you don't have thousands of tables. Even if you want to keep the orders in the database after they're served, you could add a field `active` to separate out the current ones.

Then your query is simple: `activeOrders = Orders.find({active: true}).fetch()`. The `fetch` returns an array, which you could loop through several times for each of your views, using nested if and for loops as necessary to dig down into the child objects. See also Underscore's `_.pluck`. You don't need to get everything right with some complicated Mongo query, and in fact your app will run faster if you query once and process the results however many times you need to.